# Flask WT Forms DateTimeLocal Field is not sending data

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to implement DateTimeLocalField in Flask WT Forms however the field does not return data. The other fields work fine.

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms.fields import DateTimeLocalField

class AddLegForm(FlaskForm):
    origin_datetime = DateTimeLocalField('Origin Time')
```

In views.py:

```
@loads_blueprint.route('/add_leg/<load_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_leg(load_id):    
    leg = db.session.query(Legs)
    form = AddLegForm()   
    print(type(form.origin_datetime.data))
    print(form.origin_datetime.data)
```

The print statements show:

```
<class 'NoneType'>
None
```

There are also `StringField`'s in my form and all of the other data is there.

Minimal HTML:

```
  <form method="POST", action="/loads/add_leg/{{load_id}}">        
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}  
    <div class="form-outline mb-4">          
      {{ form.origin_datetime.label }} 
      {{ form.origin_datetime(class_="form-control", size=32) }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-end">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a format issue, what if you use:

```
origin_datetime = DateTimeLocalField('Origin Time', format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
```